# retrieve(select) datetime from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, datetime

I have stored a variable in database(sqlite) with datetime data type. Now I want to select or retrieve that particular variable .

How can I select or retrieve datetime variable from sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code which may help you:

```
NSString *getSpeakerQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select dateTime from table;"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statementGet;

[self openDB];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3DB, [getSpeakerQuery UTF8String],-1, &statementGet, nil)== SQLITE_OK) 
{  
    while  (sqlite3_step(statementGet) == SQLITE_ROW)
    { 
        NSstring *dateTime=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statementGet, 0)]];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statementGet); 
}
```

where, openDB is a function to open database and in file path specify the database name

```
-(void) openDB {

if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &sqlite3DB) != SQLITE_OK ) {
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3DB);
    NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");
}
```

}

```
-(NSString *) filePath 
{

NSArray *path =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
return  [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database name"];
}
```